# Global variable referenced in section '.text' of main.o defined in discarded section '.bss'

Tags: c, gcc

In my main.c, I have `int cursor = 0;`.

This is later used in a function, where I use `cursor += 1`.

When I compile / link, I get an error:

`cursor' referenced in section .text' of main.o: defined in discarded section .bss' of main.o`

I'm relatively new to using GCC. I used to use MSVC previously, but I never got an error like this. Is there something I need to add into the linker script so it does not discard the BSS section?

Thanks

Comment: Definitely. Your linker script is excluding the .bss section.

Comment: Are you building on Unix or Windows?  What have you got in your linker script?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it will help. You could try:

```
static int cursor = 0;
```

another thing you could try is, put:

```
int cursor;
```

as the global and then in main() put cursor=0; maybe it doesn't like initializing the global?

BSS is for uninitialized globals. So for some reason I think it's not initializing your cursor variable. So moving the initialization into the main() routine might fix it.

Comment: The issue is that his .bss doesn't exist because it's being excluded by the linker script.

Comment: Thanks, it definitely was the linker script. I added this:

 .bss : {
  *(.bss)
 }

Now it works